# Why my list doesn't increment?

Tags: c#, wcf

my client returns an object and I want to store that object to a list of type of the object. I'm debugging and using the default windows client but while I am adding an object watching my list at the breakpoint only shows the latest object I passed.

```
List<CompositeType> data= new List<CompositeType>();

    public void fromClient(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add(composite);            
        }       
    }
```

This is in my IService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void fromClient(CompositeType composite);       
}

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    private string name;
    private float cpuUsage;
    private float ramAvailable;

    [DataMember]
    public string nameR
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name= value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public float cpuUsageR
    {
        get { return cpuUsage; }
        set { cpuUsage = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public float ramAvailableR
    {
        get { return ramAvailable; }
        set { ramAvailable = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The list isn't going to survive the single request - the service instance isn't persistent. If you need persistence, you need to provide it yourself, e.g. database, session...

Comment: you need to have a backing store i.e a database or appfabric caching to store the data. a single request will not persist in memory a collection you are holding unless the service is designed as a singleton of some kind.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Comment: Added  `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` and it's working. Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

please make your List data= new List();
as

static List data= new List();

As previously (without static) it was generated when client calling it..
now it will preserve the state and you can add any number of objects you want to.

Comment: Using static for things like that is often a bad idea - just imagine what will happen when multiple clients need to be supported.